# Undefined variable en login con JWT

Tags: php, jwt

Estoy haciendo un login con laravel 5 y Json Web Token (JWT), y cuando trato de probarlo me arroja el siguiente error

> ErrorException in JwtAuth.php line 72: Undefined variable: decoded

Mi helper JwtAuth

```
public function checkToken($jwt, $getIdentity = false){
        $auth = false;

     try{
         $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $this->key, array('HS256'));
     }catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e){
         $auth = false;
     }catch(\DomainException $e){
         $auth = false;
     }

     if(is_object($decoded) && isset($decoded->sub)){
         $auth = true;
     }else{
         $auth = false;
     }

     if($getIdentity){
         return $decoded;
     }

     return $auth;
}
```

Concretamente la linea 72 seria

```
if(is_object($decoded) && isset($decoded->sub)){
    $auth = true;
}else{
    $auth = false;
}
```

Porque me salta este error, porque segun entiendo mi variable `$decoded` la defino en mi `try catch`

Comment: ¿Que te sale cuando haces un `var_dump($decoded);` en la línea donde creas el JWT con `JWT::decode(...)`?

Comment: No me aparece nada, el mismo error, creo que ni siquiera esta entrando al `try - catch`, talvez por eso me sale `undefined`

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer `$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $this->key, array('HS256'));` y el `var_dump($decoded);` con un `die();` fuera del bloque del `try/catch` y un copy paste de lo que te sale? Te tendría que salir como mínimo un `Notice: undefined` de nuevo o `null`.

Comment: me sale `SignatureInvalidException in JWT.php line 97:
Signature verification failed`

Answer (score 0):

Corriendo tu código: Si la siguiente linea falla

```
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $this->key, array('HS256'));
```

La variable $decoded nunca sera definida y caerá en alguno de los catch, pero luego el compilador seguira su curso y llegara a esta linea

```
if(is_object($decoded) && isset($decoded->sub))
```

Al no existir la variable $decoded te saltara el error mencionado, la solución el poner ese **if** dentro del **try**

Suerte